# A value of type 'Type' can't be returned from the method 'createState' because it has a return type of 'State<RegisterView>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I got This Weird Error

> "A value of type 'Type' can't be returned from the method 'createState' because it has a return type of 'State'."

````
@override
 State<RegisterView> createState() => _RegisterViewState;
 }
   class _RegisterViewState extends State<RegisterView> {
   late final TextEditingController _email;
   late final TextEditingController _password;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be `_RegisterViewState()`

```dart
State<RegisterView> createState() => _RegisterViewState();// here ()
```

```dart
  @override
  State<RegisterView> createState() => _RegisterViewState();
}

class _RegisterViewState extends State<RegisterView> {
```